# Using postgresql arrays to implement "following users"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, postgresql, database-schema

A common way to have users "follow" each other is to have a **relationships** table with **follower_id** and **following_id** columns, and then reference followers/following with a has_many :through on the user model.

Would there be any downside to instead just use postgresql arrays? Specifically, having **followers** and **following** array columns on the users table, which will maintain a list of user ids who follow each other. You can then fetch the users with **User.where(id: user.followers)**.

A similar approach is commonly done using Tagging (http://makandracards.com/makandra/28641-tagging-in-rails-4-using-postgres-arrays), so I'm wondering if there's any reason this approach would be a bad idea for building out a system where users can follow each other.

Comment: Main problem would be the reverse query, to get followees

Comment: That's what the 'following' array I mentioned would be for (unless I'm misunderstanding what you mean by followees).

Comment: Ah so you'd manage two arrays representing the same stuff independently? Why not but beware of sync

Comment: Can you do join queries, updates etc. without totally hacking AR?

Comment: Good point about how it would play in AR. The way I figure, no matter what you can get an AR relation of users who you're following (User.where(id: user.following)) or users who are following you (User.where(id: user.followers), so any joins/updates can be applied there.  Maybe there's a case where that's still not enough though, hmm.

Comment: I think updating the arrays is painful. If someone stops following, I believe you have to rewrite the entire column. Also, a lot of default queries, might to a `select * from users` and you are probably getting data you don't need all the time.

Comment: If you UNfollow a user, there'd be two updates: remove user's id from self.following and remove self.id from user.followers. Not painful, array actions are native to postgres, so I'm totally ok with that. Default `select *` statements don't worry me either because having it fetch arrays of integers seems minor, and if it's not, I would just optimize the selects.  I feel like these are all solid points, but no smoking gun yet for me. I seriously might run with this approach; maybe it's one of those things I won't foresee a problem with until I fully implement it.